# como pasar este codigo de php a js

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
  
$inteligencias = array("espacial" => $e, "cinetico_corporal" => $c, "musical" => $m, "interpersonal" => $i, "intrapersonal" => $r, "naturalista" => $n, "linguistica" => $l, "logica_matematica" => $g);

        arsort($inteligencias);

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($inteligencias as $inte => $cant) {
            $porcent = $cant / 15 * 100;

            echo $inte . "\n con un\n" . $porcent . "%";   
            $i++;
            if ($i == 3) {
                $i = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Adicionalmente, ¿Qué valores deberían ir en $e, $c, etc?

Comment: También sería de mucha utilidad si explicas lo que debe hacer el código, ya que no explicas cuál es el propósito del mismo. Te recomiendo leer [ask]. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento para agregar más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Hola claramente hicieron falta más detalles como te indican en los comentarios, entonces tomaré por hecho que en cada variable de tu array asociativo tienes un valor numérico, ya que noto que ese está aplicando una operación en el ciclo FOR, tu ejercicio en JS quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
const inteligencias = {
    espacial: 200,
    cinetico_corporal: 300,
    musical: 100,
    interpersonal: 500,
    intrapersonal: 90,
    naturalista: 20,
    linguistica: 100,
    logica_matematica: 700
}

const inteligenciasOrdenadas = Object.entries(inteligencias).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]);

var acumulador = 0;

inteligenciasOrdenadas.every((element) => {
    acumulador += 1
    const porcent = element[1] / 15 * 100
    console.log(element[0] + ' con un ', + porcent + '%');
    if (acumulador === 3 ) {
        acumulador = 0
        return false
    }

    return true
})
```

Documentación:

- [Método Entries JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Método Sort JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Método Every JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)